# How can I perform for loops in grouped data python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have been trying different methods to detect an aborted landing. In the code I have put up several conditions using a for loop but it does not give me the desired result. The goal is to get a 'TRUE' value at index 2 and 4.

Below you can find a dummy dataframe. First I created new columns to calculate the difference between the current altitude compared to the previous altitude of that specific aircraft. Then the NA values and extreme values are filtered. Once that has been done, I created a new column with an initial value of 'FALSE'.

Then, the for-loop should check every row to see if the altitude change is greater than 30 ft, if that is the case, a 'TRUE' should be assigned starting from that row until landing (altitude = 0)

However, this for-loop does not seem to work when I use a dataframe including different aircraft id's.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'aircraft':     ['1', '1', '1', '2','1','1' ,'2','3','2','3', '3'],
        'altitude':     [1000, 900, 1200, 1000, 1400, 0, 890, 1050, 750, 850, 700],
    })

    # Creating two new columns showing the difference in altitude between transmissions
    df["altitude_shift"] = df.groupby(['aircraft'])["altitude"].shift(1)
    df["altitude_difference"] = df["altitude"] - df["altitude_shift"]
    
    
    # Replacing the NaN values with 0
    df.replace(np.nan,0)
    df['altitude_difference'] = df['altitude_difference'].fillna(0)
    
    # Filtering out the negative values, showing only the points where the aircraft climbs during approach
    df["altitude_climb"] = np.where(df["altitude_difference"]<0,
                                             0, df["altitude_difference"])
    
    # Filtering out the extreme climb values
    df['altitude_climb'] = np.where(df['altitude_climb']>800,
                                              0, df['altitude_climb'])
    
    # Creating a new column with False as initial value
    df['aborted_landing'] = False
    
    # Creates True values if the aircraft gains more than 30 ft between alt reports
    # The elif statement checks if the aircraft is on ground
    for indices, row in df.iterrows():
        if df.at[indices, 'altitude_climb'] > 30:
            df.loc[indices:, 'aborted_landing'] = True
        elif df.at[indices, 'altitude'] <= 0:
            df.loc[indices:, 'aborted_landing'] = False
        break
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: hi ANB! please try to be more specific, showing only what is really needed for the community to understand your question. Technically: what you're trying to do and what is the error you are getting back?

Comment: Hi Renato! The problem that I am running into is probably the setup of the for-loop at the end. This loop does not seem to give me the result that I want, which is a True value at index 2 and 4. When I run this code for an individual aircraft, for example on a dataframe of only aircraft 1, then I do not have this problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please update your question with a [example]: remove nonessential parts of your code (for reproducing the problem), explain your code, and clearly explain your problem and desired result.

Answer (score 0):

The for loop at the end of your code is only doing a condition check on the 0th row of your df.  Is the break at the end of your for loop supposed to be there?

Comment: The break seemed to work when I used a dataframe with only one aircraft id

Comment: Please add as comment instead of answer

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the need for:

> Creating a new column with False as initial value df['aborted_landing'] = False

and the for loop.

just do `df['aborted_landing]= df['altitude_climb'] >30`

Comment: That should normally work as well, but the goal with the for loop was to keep showing True values once df['altitude_climb']>30 was detected until the aircraft has reached an altitude of 0.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you mean... is this some sort of a stream data, and you want to dynamically assign the correct boolean value to 'aborted_landing' ?

Comment: It is difficult for me to explain, but I have a dataset of different aircraft that performed a landing at a certain airport. And I was trying to detect the flights that resulted in an aborted landing by giving a 'TRUE' when an aircraft climbed 30ft compared to the previous altitude report. But I want to keep those 'TRUE' values for all the rows of that aircraft starting from the moment that df['altitude_climb'] >30 until df['altitude']<=0